# How to test if Cython property is generator?

Tags: python, types, generator, cython, isinstance

In IPython, I can see that a property of a Cython class is a generator by simply defining it and then calling:

```
%%cython
cdef class SomeCls:
    property x:
        def __get__(self):
            yield 1
```

The call looks like

```
SomeCls().x
# prints <generator at 0x102f61ee8>
```

I am having trouble testing if that property is a generator:

```
import types
print(isinstance(SomeCls().x, types.GeneratorType))
# prints False

import inspect
print(inspect.isgeneratorfunction(SomeCls.x))
# prints False
```

How can I determine whether a property of a Cython class is a generator?

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Comment: Testing against `types.GeneratorType` works just fine when _not_ using cython...

Comment: Don't be picky about where you get help!  As an experienced poster, I often answer with short comments.  For a regular answer I spend more time, providing working examples and explanations.

Comment: This _doesn't_ fix the problem, but Cython now supports the standard `@property` syntax (which I think is now preferred since it matches the rest of Python). It behaves exactly the same though with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doesn't the usual way work?

First, as you already probably know, there is no difference between `inspect.isgeneratorfunction(...)` and `isinstance(..., types.GeneratorType)` - the inspect-module just [calls](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7cd25434164882c2093ea41ccfc7b95a05cd5cbd/Lib/inspect.py#L203) `isinstance(..., types.GeneratorType)`.

On the other hand, `types.GeneratorType` is [defined as](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/types.py#L18)

```
def _g():
    yield 1
GeneratorType = type(_g())
```

CPython uses PyGenObject ([here code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Include/genobject.h#L34), [here documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/gen.html)) for generators, there is no fancy logic for the comparison as for some ABC-classes, so the `isinstance` will boil down to comparing the C-object types.

However, Cython returns a [`__pyx_CoroutineObject`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/bd023b4e4f375ce0c90e85a2bf6302565f9276be/Cython/Utility/Coroutine.c#L365) for generators (just check the cythonized code to see)

```
typedef PyObject *(*__pyx_coroutine_body_t)(PyObject *, PyThreadState *, PyObject *);
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    __pyx_coroutine_body_t body;
    PyObject *closure;
    ...
    int resume_label;
    char is_running;
} __pyx_CoroutineObject;
```

which has nothing to do with `PyGenObject` as far as `isinstance`is concerned - it doesn't really care whether `generator` is in the name of the type (but for us humans it can be really puzzling, because `type(obj)` says "generator").

So you will have to roll out your own version of `isgenerator`, which takes also Cython-"generators" into account. There are many ways, for example

```
%%cython
def _f():
    yield 1
CyGeneratorType = type(_f())   
def iscygenerator(o):
    return isinstance(o, CyGeneratorType)
```

and now:

```
import inspect   
def isgenerator(o):
    return inspect.isgenerator(o)  or iscygenerator(o)

isgenerator(SomeCls().x)          #  True
iscygenerator(SomeCls().x)        #  True
inspect.isgenerator(SomeCls().x)  #  False
```

Comment: This answered the question in the MWE that I posted, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem (determining the type of [this Spacy attribute](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/develop/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L456)).  However, I was able to use your example to set `SpacyGeneratorType = type(doc.subtree)` and then test against that type, like you showed.  This mostly teaches me how little I know about types in Cython.  Thanks for your help!